# Как получить сумму заказа на странице оформления заказа?

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите, как у Битрикса правильно получать сумму заказа на странице оформления заказа, в шаблоне sale.order.ajax? (там где человек выбирает способ оплаты, доставку, вводит личные данные и т.п. Там по умолчанию в правой колонке выводится итоговая сумма. Вот мне её же нужно дублировать чуть в другом месте. Знаю значение хранится в this.result.TOTAL.ORDER_PRICE, но не пойму как правильно вывести в template.php

Answer (score 0):

Непосредственно в шаблоне цена заказа в `$arResult["ORDER_PRICE"]` в виде числа и в `$arResult["JS_DATA"]["TOTAL"]` в виде массива с различными вариантами представления (со скидкой и без, с форматированием и без форматирования).

Но сама верстка компонента формируется на JS, так что без правки скриптов скорее всего не обойтись.